# Doubts about __bridge, _bridge_retain and _bridge_transfer

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, types, casting

I have read about `__bridge`, `_bridge_retain` and `_bridge_transfer` and did some experiments. However the output does not coincide with what I was expecting. In particular, I have the following code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *test;
@end

@implementation ViewController

CFStringRef cfString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.test = @"123";
    cfString = (__bridge CFStringRef)self.test;
    self.test = nil;    
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%@", cfString);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.test);
}
```

I expect the program to crash, based on the following reasoning: `_bridge` does not transfer ownership, so while casting `self.test` to `cfString`, there is no retainCount increment. Once `self.test` is set to `nil`, `ARC` will step in and dealloc the string. So that portion of memory is freed, but `cfString` is still pointing there, resulting in a pointer bad access exception. In contrast to my reasoning, the output is 123 and null, and of course the program does not crash.

Moreover, if I replace

```
self.test = nil;
```

with

```
CFRelease(cfString);
```

I expect the program to crash as well due to a similar reasoning. Even stranger is that the output is now 123 and 123.

Can anyone kindly elaborate why? Btw, the term ownership always troubles me, some explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should repeat this test with something other than `NSString` object. Be very wary drawing any memory management conclusions on the basis of `NSString` behavior.

Comment: The word is **crash**.  The program **crashes**.  It does not *crush*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a constant string. This is put straight into the programs memory so the reference is unexpectedly remaining valid despite the fact that it shouldn't. Use something less constant than a constant string and your program will brake like you think.

Comment: So the chunk of memory where the character sequence resides did not get freed up? And why self.test = nil and CFRelease gives different behaviour?

Comment: That's pretty much it. making a mutable copy of the string may do it, although without actually mutating the string it may be clever enough to continue referencing the constant string, so it may be an idea to also actually mutate your mutable copy. You can use the `mutableCopy` method to make the mutable copy!

Comment: Just experimented with NSNumber and CFNumberRef, and the program crushed happily as expected. Thanks James!

Comment: Be careful with `NSNumber` too. Some `NSNumber` objects are constants (I believe the `NSNumber` objects for the integers 0 to 12).

Comment: @maddy Also, some architectures implement NSNumber as tagged pointers.  There is no allocation at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you base your example on a literal NSString value.

In objective-C, constant NSString (constant values known at compile time) are never released. In fact, their main memory managment methods are like:

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    id _uniqueInstance = [self _singletonInstanceOfClass];

    if( _uniqueInstance == nil )
        _uniqueInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];

    return _uniqueInstance;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    (void)zone;
    return self;
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)retainCount {
    return NSUIntegerMax;  // denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (oneway void)release {
    //do nothing
    return;
}

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}
```

As you can see, releasing them is not possible.